# Chrome can't play audio after currentTime is changed

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I am running the following code in Chrome:

```
audioEl = document.getElementById('#mySound');
audioEl.play();
```

Then half way through the sound playing back I'm running this code:

```
audioEl.pause();
audioEl.currentTime = 0;
audioEl.play();
```

The result is that the last call to `play()` returns a pending promise that never returns until I call `pause()` again, at which point the promise is rejected with `The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause().`.

The same code works fine on Firefox and I can't see any logical problems with it. Is there a way around this? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Why do you need to pause? Why don't you just use `audioEl.currentTime = 0;` without pausing?

Comment: The same thing happens

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a problem with OGG files. MP3 works fine.